# How can I fix the circular dependency between my S3 bucket and SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework

I am trying to write a [serverless](https://www.serverless.com/) configuration for my service. A requirement is that the S3 bucket sends notifications to an SQS queue on object create events. However, when I try to deploy my service using `serverless deploy`, I get this error:

```
Serverless Error ----------------------------------------

 An error occurred: PolicyS3Bucket - Unable to validate the following destination configurations (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: 4D25CQFZN0R2Q9FG; S3 Extended Request ID: dLfKHJgOnDUcAF3xwN9EgW9LibP3bt7ITj7PyuCXs2qH6Qvmn2iZu7aXYbbUdqptPvgvjwkcWYM=; Proxy: null).
```

I found [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-circular-dependency-cloudformation/) which (if I understand correctly) explains that I have a circular dependency between my S3 bucket and my SQS queue, and that I must fix this circular dependency in order to be able to successfully deploy my service.

This page explains that I can use [`Fn::Sub`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) or [`Fn::Join`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) to fix the circular dependency. Based on this suggestion, I modified my configuration from the original version to a new version as below, using `Sub`:

**`cfn.s3.yml` (original version)**

```
Resources:
  PolicyS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: ${self:custom.config.policyBucketName}
      AccessControl: Private
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
      NotificationConfiguration:
        QueueConfigurations:
          - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
            Queue: !GetAtt SQSQueue.Arn
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - BucketKeyEnabled: true
            ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              KMSMasterKeyID: !Ref CustomMasterKey
              SSEAlgorithm: aws:kms
      Tags: ${redacted}
```

**`cfn.s3.yml` (new version, change in bold)**

```
Resources:
  PolicyS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: ${self:custom.config.policyBucketName}
      AccessControl: Private
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
      NotificationConfiguration:
        QueueConfigurations:
          - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
            Queue: !Sub arn:aws:sqs:${self:provider.region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${self:custom.config.sqsQueueName}
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - BucketKeyEnabled: true
            ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              KMSMasterKeyID: !Ref CustomMasterKey
              SSEAlgorithm: aws:kms
      Tags: ${redacted}
```

**My unchanged `cfn.sqs.yml`**

```
Resources:
  SQSQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: ${self:custom.config.sqsQueueName}
```

When I tried `serverless deploy` with the new version, I get the same error.

I also tried @kgiannakakis's suggestion to use [`DependsOn`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html), but I get the same error when I try that.

How can I fix my serverless configuration so that I can successfully deploy my service?

Comment: You need the region and account ID in the SQS ARN: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html

Comment: I fixed the ARN, see my updated question.

Comment: Try using the DependsOn attribute (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html), so that the Queue is created first. Still not clear to me, why there is a circular dependency between the bucket and the queue.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a circular dependency myself. I just googled "Unable to validate the following destination configurations" and that brought me to the AWS docs page I link in the question, which suggests that the error means a circular dependency. I'm new to CloudFormation and serverless, so I just assumed that error only occurs when there are circular dependencies, but that might be an incorrect assumption.

Comment: @kgiannakakis I tried `DependsOn` and I continue to get the same error.

Comment: Actually DependsOn and GetAtt have the same effect of forcing the queue to be created first. Could it be that you are using an invalid S3 bucket name (with capital letters for example)?

Comment: @kgiannakakis The bucket name should be valid. I don't show it here, but I have another S3 bucket defined earlier in the same `cfn.s3.yml` file called `ApplicationS3Bucket`, and I don't get any errors or warnings for that S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix that worked.

I had to update my `cfn.sqs.yml` to include permissions for S3 buckets to send events to the SQS queue, as below:

```
Resources:
  SQSQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: ${self:custom.config.sqsQueueName}
  S3EventQueuePolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    DependsOn: SQSQueue
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Id: SQSPolicy
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Sid: PutS3Events
            Action: SQS:SendMessage
            Resource: !GetAtt SQSQueue.Arn
            Principal:
              Service: s3.amazonaws.com
      Queues:
        - !Ref SQSQueue
```

As for my `cfn.s3.yml`, the correct way to reference the queue was

```
Queue: !GetAtt SQSQueue.Arn
```

I believe the problem was that AWS checks that the notification will be possible at deployment time, rather than letting your service fail at runtime, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60357375/8593689):

> A lot of AWS configuration allows you to connect services and they fail at runtime if they don't have permission, however S3 notification configuration does check some destinations for access.

This would mean that, since I hadn't configured my SQS queue to allow notifications from the S3 bucket, AWS noticed this misconfiguration and stopped the deployment with an error.