# Which permissions do I need to create an event notification on S3 bucket to SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have an S3 bucket saving logs, I´m configuring event notification on the bucket to publish on the SQS every time a new log is avalaible.

When I tried to setup the configuration for the event notification(I´m following this walkthrough: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/observability/8.4/monitor-aws-elastic-agent.html#aws-elastic-agent-enable-event-notification) I got the following error:
[First error, permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaAII.png)

I added that permission but it responds: invalid action that permission does not exist., so I added "s3:PutBucketNotification" permission, but whe I retry to configure the event notification I´m getting the following error:
[Even giving me permissions i get this error...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyFy0.png)

My Access policy file for SQS is like this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "example-ID",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "example-statement-ID",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": [
            "SQS:SendMessage"
        ],
        "Resource": "SQS-queue-ARN",
        "Condition": {
            "ArnLike": {
                "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:awsexamplebucket1"
            },
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:SourceAccount": "bucket-owner-account-id"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Does anybody know why this could be happening?

Comment: Did you change `awsexamplebucket1` and other parameters in the policy to match your setup?

Comment: @Marcin Yes I did, I replaced it to publish for security reasons.

Comment: is your SQS encrypted using KMS? Also try after removing: `"StringEquals": {
                "aws:SourceAccount": "bucket-owner-account-id"
            }`

Comment: Check if encryption is on for your sqs? if yes disable and then try again, if there is no encryption set, please check your `bucket-owner-account-id`

check this too https://stackoverflow.com/q/60344618/13126651

Comment: The encryption I´m using is SSE-SQS, I tried removing "StringEquals": {                 "aws:SourceAccount": "bucket-owner-account-id"             } but still not working... @AnthonyB.

Comment: I disabled the encryption but still not working, also I checked again the bucket-owner-account-id @JatinMehrotra

Comment: Are the bucket and the SQS within the same account and region?

Comment: they are in the same region but the sqs is in my account and the bucket on other account, but I can see the bucket from my account @AnthonyB.

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue. @IsNotMyIp were you able to figure this out?